# A Cryptic Tale Indeed!

Tags: story, cryptic-clues

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #46: "Tales From the Cryptic"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7128/fortnightly-topic-challenge-46-tales-from-the-cryptic)</sup>

> We begin with the most *abnormal, rosiest fables* **of** *twisted form, driven into the heart of endless deed.* It is a dark fate, *to condemn those least messed up*
>
> *Nearing a brief coma, a being with no boy is going east* **out of** *a recurring table?* There is *zeal for the initial fate every raving villain originally requested,* but *prior to reversed iron being inserted into the bore* **the** *thousand years starts with many illegitimate litigators lying every night, inexplicably undermining memories*.
>
> **An** *account found in the heart I cleaned* was saved **for when the** *extra bizarre hero contains the beginning of time*. The way **is** *disoriented on a popular drama series?* **At both** *extremities, is the corrupted send*
>
> *If we head west before we're ill, our determination* saves us before we *weep like an animal's call*. **With a** *shovel found in alcohol low in the ground* we *look up at the tap to pet* the animal, *in front of pointless beef. Before every other course,* with *perpetual broken needles, losing east, but gaining south,* we find **ice as** our *ear follows 150 Romans to negotiate*. We finally settle **as** the *muck has left dumb without an end*

**What would be an appropriate title for our story?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first step:

> Each italicised phrase is a cryptic clue.
>  The solutions to those cryptic clues are:
>  [image]
>  Text version:
>  `¶1: STORIES*; DE(FORM)ED; SLATE*`
>  `¶2: COM(-a) + (-b,-e)ING; PERIODIC ddef; FERVOR inits; B(EF<)ORE; MILLENIUM inits [sic]`
>  `¶3: _ARTICLE_; O(T_)HER*; LOST ddef; ENDS*`
>  `¶4: W+ILL; CRY ddef; _HOLLOW_; PAT<; B(-e)EF + _O_R_E; ENDLE(e→S)S*; CL+EAR; (-b)MUD<`

The second step:

> These, together with the bold words in each paragraph, form *new* cryptic clues!
>
>  ¶1: STORIES of DEFORMED SLATE → `TALES*`
>  ¶2: COMING out of PERIODIC FERVOR BEFORE MILLENIUM → `F_R_O_ + M`
>  ¶3: an ARTICLE for when the OTHER is LOST at both ENDS → `(-o)THE(-r)`
>  ¶4: WILL CRY with a HOLLOW PAT BEFORE ENDLESS ice as CLEAR as MUD → `CRY + P_T + IC(-e)`
>
>  So a fitting title is **TALES FROM THE CRYPTIC**!

---

Some feedback on the clues:

> A *lot* of these clues had extra words. Extra words are generally not allowed in cryptics; it should be possible to parse *every single word* as meaningful somehow. This is why cryptic clues often read like tabloid headlines - if the word "the" doesn't make sense in the cryptic reading, you can't use it in the clue.
>
>  Additionally, there were some indicators that didn't grammatically apply to the things they were acting on. This is also a problem: "starts apple banana cherry" cannot be parsed to mean "ABC". "[The] starts *of* apple banana cherry" *can* mean that, but without the "of" it doesn't mean what you want it to.
>
>  [image]